# Can not display Image read with pydicom (Invalid Image Shape)

Tags: python, pydicom

I am writing a simple code to read dicom images, But it gives me an error when i try to displaying it whith matplotlib
 here is my code :

```
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = pydicom.dcmread("C:/Users/A763194/Desktop/Cone beam/IMG.dcm")  # plan dataset
print(ds.PatientName)
print(ds.Rows)
print(ds.Columns)
plt.imshow(ds.pixel_array)
```

I expect the output of Images dicom, but it gives the error below :

> TypeError: Invalid shape (601, 601, 601) for image data

Answer (score 4):

Just change last line to:

```
plt.imshow(ds.pixel_array.mean(axis=0))
```